# how to get a vsphere VM's creation time

Tags: ruby, sdk, vsphere

How do I get a vSphere VM's creation time using the ruby SDK?  I can get the VM instances, but there doesn't seem to be a property that shows when the VM is created.

```
api_client = VSphereAutomation::ApiClient.new(configuration)
VSphereAutomation::CIS::SessionApi.new(api_client).create('')
vm_api = VSphereAutomation::VCenter::VMApi.new(api_client)
vms = vm_api.list({filter_power_states: ["POWERED_ON"]})
...
# this will get a specific VM information but nothing about creation time.
vm_api.get('vm-34122')
```

Comment: [get](https://vmware.github.io/vsphere-automation-sdk-ruby/VSphereAutomation/VCenter/VMApi.html#get-instance_method) returns a [VcenterVMResult](https://vmware.github.io/vsphere-automation-sdk-ruby/VSphereAutomation/VCenter/VcenterVMResult.html). It looks like this has an attribute map and hash to view all the properties, but I can't find anything that gives the created/updated times. That detail may not be saved.

Comment: @akerr in the UI, it does show that kind of information, so it must be getting those from somewhere, which is what my original question is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output is sourced from the vSphere Web Services API via a new property in the [Virtual Machine](https://vdc-download.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/b50dcbbf-051d-4204-a3e7-e1b618c1e384/538cf2ec-b34f-4bae-a332-3820ef9e7773/vim.VirtualMachine.html) managed object, which is nested in the [ConfigInfo](https://vdc-download.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/b50dcbbf-051d-4204-a3e7-e1b618c1e384/538cf2ec-b34f-4bae-a332-3820ef9e7773/vim.vm.ConfigInfo.html) and can be referenced by `createDate`. Full property path: `vm.config.createdate`

Worth noting, this information isn't available in the REST (eg. vSphere Automation) API for vSphere, so you'll need to use rbvmomi to access it. Also, if you happen to pull non-sensical dates, that's likely due to the VM being created prior to this property being introduced into the the API in vSphere 6.7.

Comment: Do you know which api under rbvmomi is this property listed under?  I don't see that under the virtualMachine portion https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rbvmomi/1.10.0/RbVmomi/VIM/VirtualMachine.

Comment: Perhaps you're hitting this issue? 
https://github.com/vmware/rbvmomi/issues/155

Comment: I figured it out that `vm` is the VirtualMachine object.